# Issue While Loop Apache Status

Tags: arrays, apache, bash, loops

Do you know why this loop returns directory listing results??

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/httpd fullstatus | while read line
do
echo $line
done

71-0 - 0/0/410 . 7.74 47987 0 0.0 0.00 0.76 127.0.0.1 
OPTIONS = bin boot dev error_log etc home lib lib64 lost+found media mnt nohup.out opt proc root sbin selinux srv sys test tmp usr var HTTP/1.0
72-0 - 0/0/103 . 0.14 48912 0 0.0 0.00 0.13 127.0.0.1 
OPTIONS = bin boot dev error_log etc home lib lib64 lost+found media mnt nohup.out opt proc root sbin selinux srv sys test tmp usr var HTTP/1.0
```

It should returns only apache status.

```
71-0 - 0/0/410 . 7.74 48231 0 0.0 0.00 0.76 127.0.0.1 
OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
72-0 - 0/0/103 . 0.14 49157 0 0.0 0.00 0.13 127.0.0.1 
OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of this line on output

```
OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
```

shell expands "*" used in "echo" arguments as list of files in current directory. This script's output will differ depending on $CWD of calling shell.

Go to any chosen directory, and type "echo *" command.

Answer (score 1):

Because `*` gets interpreted.

Remember:

## ALWAYS QUOTE YOUR VARIABLES

In this case:

```
echo "$line"
```

Answer (score 0):

Piotr already answered the question. Just some addition. I would suggest not to pipe anything to `while`! It will create another [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) process which is wasting resources and You will face to problems if you define a variable inside the `while` loop and you want to use it outside the loop. I may suggest to use some other solution, like:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
echo "$line"
done < <(/usr/sbin/httpd fullstatus)
```